# Add Alert for Nav Bar Back Action Before Go to View Controller

Tags: swift, navigation, tableview, back

So i have an add entry vc and for the back button I want an alert to pop up to question the user if they want to continue because their info will be lost. I have been reading and found to use this function but it doesn't work as I want it to. The alert appears when the view loads and after it goes back to the main vc. Here is the code and some pictures. Thanks.

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure?", message: "If You Proceed, All Data On This Page Will Be Lost", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(action)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to create a custom backButton which targets an action that displays the alert. Then just check if the user presses ok, pop the viewController. if the user presses cancel just dismiss the alert.

Comment: The vc automatically has a back button because its embedded in nav controller. @GaloTorresSevilla

Comment: You can hide it and use you custom one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add custom back button in your `viewDidload` like this way

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backAction(sender:)))
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton

        }
```

This is action method of back button so you can add your alert here and add action whatever you want like this way:

```
@objc func backAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure?", message: "If You Proceed, All Data On This Page Will Be Lost", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I did this but it got . rid of the back arrow on the default back button form the nav bar. any way to retain the back arrow in the title with the text back?

Comment: You can add back arrow icon custom

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    }

    func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure?", message: "If You Proceed, All Data On This Page Will Be Lost", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let stayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Stay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
          print("Stay")
        }
        let leaveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "GO Back", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
           self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
```